# Why does express still use require instead of es6 import to boot up an express application?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to teach myself how to use Express, and don't understand why

`const express = require('express');`

works, but

`import express from 'express';`

doesn't. I have node version 9.4.0 on my machine. Given express's docs use require syntax, it seems es6 import syntax isn't supported. I'm just trying to understand why, as I would think that would depend on the node environment installed on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js does not support import statement till now. Refer [node.green](http://node.green/) link to see Node.js version compatibility.

Comment: Yes, though I couldn't find ECMAScript Modules in the link you provided. However, as of version 9, they are available if you use the --experimental-modules and an *.mjs file extension in your app (https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).

Comment: Have you tried using the ```npm i esm``` module for enabling the es6 features